# completely remove chef off my server

Tags: linux, chef, rhel6, chef-server

I am trying to install chef onto my RHEL6 machine. I have followed a old guide that is not relevant and I am getting some errors now and I want to fully wipe chef off this server. I tried following there instructions of running the following cmd "chef-server-ctl uninstall"

But seems as this command does not really remove everything it just shuts some process's down. Whats the best way to fully purge this off my machine without fully re-imaging this machine ?

Comment: What guide did you follow (is there a link)?

Comment: I also lost the link. But my main issue was related to users and organizations either existing and that was causing a bunch of conflicts. So if you have any recommendations on how to fully purge this that would be great.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'organizations', but you basically need to undo what you did in order to clean it up.
However, if I were you I'd just go ahead with setting chef as usual and resolve problems as they arise.

Comment: when i speak of 'organizations' im speaking of groups. such as you can have users associated to groups. Anyway if I knew what did I would just fix that one thing but I really am not sure so that is why I just want to start over.